# testng.xml loaded testng setXmlSuites class is not support @autowired

Tags: xml, spring-boot, testng, multi-module

I have a testng.xml file like :

```
<test name="Api_Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mytest.AppTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testA"></include>
                    <include name="testB"></include>
                    <include name="testC"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
</test>
```

I load This file in my spring service like :

```
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
suite = (List <XmlSuite>)(new Parser(suiteFile).parse());
testng.setXmlSuites(suite);
testng.run();
```

My Test class run successfully but AppTest is get autowired dependancy as null.

AppTest.class as :

```
    @Component
public class BCAppTest{

    @Autowired
    private BCAppSteps bcAppSteps;

    @Test
    public void testA(){...}

    @Test
    public void testB(){...}
}
```

bcAppSteps is null here although project is up and running and test class called successfully.

Comment: How does your BCAppSteps look like?

Comment: @Lenar BCAppSteps is a simple bean and its only get null when I load suite.xml using testng class as shown in code. Other wise its working fine when I run the flow as usual spring injection.

Comment: Check if anything Spring specific works when you run tests this way. Probably it shouldn't.

Actually I've never run tests this way. Why not to run with Maven for example?

Comment: Thanks @Lenar for your quick response. I have run tests using maven and I do it on build time like mvn clean install -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml. Its work fine. but my objective is I need a service which is deployed i.e. rest api and when I call this api it execute all test by executing testng.xml. Its also work but dependancy which injected in test class is null so test not working properly.

Comment: OK. If your service is deployed and running that means that bean should be already instantiated/injected. Check that without running tests. If the bean is null that means the issue is not related to tests that you run.

If the bean is not null then the problem is that you're trying to change/re-instantiate the bean in tests and failed. 

It's too difficult to diagnose without seeing the patient :)

Comment: @Lenar thanks. you were right.